# Not found 404 in Apache2 using the symfony framework

Tags: php, apache, symfony, debian

I took the configuration from the official website here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html (the one without using .htaccess), I put it here: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf. I also changed some paths and now I've got this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public
<Directory /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
```

When I type in 'localhost', I get the message that there's no route for '/' and that's true (this message is from symfony). But I do have the route for /lucky/number and when I type in 'localhost/lucky/number' I get a 404 Not Found message. What can be wrong with my Apache web server? If I use the built-in php web server, everything works. But I can't figure out what's wrong with Apache.

Comment: You using `domain.tld` in `ServerName`

Comment: I have deleted it, thanks, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: and yes, I have reloaded my apache web server

Comment: How did you configure your routes in Symfony?

Comment: In the same way as here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

Comment: no there aren't

Comment: done, it hasn't helped :(

Comment: I guess the symfony is supposed to give me messages back, whatever the uri is. But it only shows me its messages when I just type in 'localhost/' (and this message is the message that there are no routes for '/'), when I type in something like 'localhost/blahblagrffgdfgds' then the apache itself sends me a 404 Not Found message, although the symfony is supposed to do this. (It's supposed to say that there are no routes for 
 'blahblagrffgdfgds')

Comment: @ShadeWe Did you create the `/blahblagrffgdfgds` route in `config/routes.yaml` or using `Annotation`?

Comment: I didn't created it

Answer (score 4):

Its is wrong:

```
<Directory /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

it will disable mod_rewrite, according to link https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html, this is used to:

> optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
>   which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
>   not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack

It is an optional example to configure the assets and not the routes, in this folder would be the assets:

```
 <Directory /var/www/project/public/bundles>
```

### Fixed:

First enable mod_write using terminal:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

In Debian:

```
$ su
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

And after try use this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public
    <Directory /home/shade/Documents/webchat/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And restart apache in Terminal:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Or in Debian:

```
$ su
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

---

### Creating routes

You can use `config/routes.yaml`, first create a Controller in `src/Controller/LuckyController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

And create a Controller to `/` in `src/Controller/DefaultController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>FooBar</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

After in `config/routes.yaml` file, put this:

```
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::index' }

# the "app_lucky_number" route name is not important yet
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

Or you can use Annotions, first install annotions:

```
composer require annotations
```

If your composer is not global use:

```
php composer.phar require annotations
```

And change lucky.php for:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function number()
    {
        // this looks exactly the same
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It hasn't helped :( I have also changed `Order Allow,Deny` to `Require all granted`.

Comment: I've got the same code as you listed in `creating routes` (using routes.yaml). When I type in 'localhost/lucky/number' nothing seems to work.

Comment: @ShadeWe Are you using `symfony/skeleton` or only "Symfony core"?

Comment: symfony/skeleton

Comment: I tried to change the route to `app_lucky_number:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number` and that worked! What can be wrong with other URIs that aren't '/'?

Comment: @ShadeWe I'm testing

Comment: @ShadeWe I tested in my machine and work fine, see test in Opera Browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18jU7.png - Note: I used `webchat/public` folder as well as in your project

Comment: Thanks for helping and wasting your time :) , I will try to do something else then.

Comment: That's quite ridiculous, but I couldn't get the things working because the rewriting module wasn't loaded, that all. I couldn't even imagine that this was the problem.

Comment: @ShadeWe It's normal, I have not realized that I was using "ifmodule", I would get a possibility, good thing I could solve :)

Comment: @ShadeWe I update answer with command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` for enable mod_write